# Orthogonality of matrix with orthogonal rows.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality

> Suppose an $n \times n$ matrix A has orthogonal rows. Show there is a diagonal matrix $D$ such that $DA$ is orthogonal.

If $A$ has orthogonal rows, then $A^T$ must be orthogonal. It follows that $(A^T)^TA^T=AA^T = I$. By right multiplying by $(A^T)^{-1}$ and left multiplying by $A^T$, we get $A^TA = I$. Thus, $A$ itself must be orthogonal. Thus, take $D=I$ and we are done, as $DA=A$, which was proven to be orthogonal.

Does this look alright? Have I made any errors?

Comment: Hint: left-multiplying by a diagonal matrix $D$ multiplies each row by the corresponding diagonal entry of $D$.

Comment: You need an additional assumption that none of the rows consist entirely of zeros.

Answer (score 1):

Orthogonal rows means that for each rows $r_i,r_j$ we have $r_i\cdot r_j=0$ if $i\neq j$. However, it does not tells us that $r_i\cdot r_i=1$, which is required to be an orthogonal matrix. However, if you choose the diagonal entries $d_i$ of $D$ such that $d_i=||r_i||^{-1}$, you can check that the rows of $DA$ are now not just orthogonal, but orthonormal. (And hence $(DA)^\top DA=I$). Your original calculation that $A^\top A=I$ is incorrect because while $A A^\top$ will be diagonal, the diagonal entries will be $||r_i||^2$. And $A^\top A$ is not necessarily even diagonal, as seen in @DisintegrationByParts example.

Answer (score 1):

The following has orthogonal rows but not orthogonal columns:
$$
     \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ -2 & 2 \end{pmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 1):

There's a slight issue with your argument due to the fact that the name "orthogonal matrix" is a bit misleading. The columns of an orthogonal matrix $A$ are *orthonormal*, not just orthogonal.

You can see the issue in the example
$$ A=\begin{bmatrix}2&0\\0&3\end{bmatrix} $$
The rows (and columns) of $A$ are orthogonal, but $A$ is not an orthogonal matrix.

Fortunately this is easily fixed, provided that none of the rows of $A$ are the zero vector. The diagonal matrix $D$ should have the reciprocals of the lengths of the rows of $A$ on its diagonal.

Comment: Ah, alright. So, it is not correct to say that $A^T$ is orthogonal?

Comment: Exactly, $A^T$ is not necessarily orthogonal. But once you multiply by $D$ everything should work out (again, provided that no row of $A$ is the zero vector).

Answer (score 0):

Since your matrix has orthogonal rows, you have that $AA^T = S$ for some diagonal matrix $S$ (verify this).  $S$ is not necessarily the identity since the rows are not known to be **orthonormal**.

Now we want a diagonal matrix $D$ such that $DA$ is orthogonal.  That requires $$I = (DA)(DA)^T = DA A^T D^T = D S D^T$$

So if you can produce a diagonal matrix $D$ which achieves $DSD = I$, then you are all set!